# Create personal wireless network on laptop

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, network-manager, adhoc

I have a WiFi Network, now I have connected my laptop to the WiFi Network. And it is working fine I'm able to access the internet via WiFi.

But I want to create other network on my laptop so that I can connect my mobile phone to the my laptop network.

Means, my laptop is already connected to WiFi network (xyz). Now I want to create one wireless network on my laptop. So that I can connect my mobile phone to laptop network and access the internet on mobile. But I don't want to lost my `laptop and WiFi connection that is already connected.

I tried to create the wireless network on my laptop, but when I created my personal wireless network I lost my wifi-laptop connection.

I don't know it is possible or not.

Comment: If you have only one wifi card in your laptop, you cannot. Network card can only handle one connexion type (Hotspot or client) at a time.
But why don't you try to connect your mobile phone to the network you are already using for your laptop?

Comment: @Dremor - I don't have any problem to connect my mobile phone to network that already i have. But I just wanted to know can we create the chain of network. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Should I put it as answer?

Comment: yes. you can put it as answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one wifi card in your laptop, you cannot. Network card can only handle one connexion type (Hotspot or client) at a time.